# Button Like In Django- Getting likes For only the First Post

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am Trying to implement like buttons in my Html using Django,  jquery, and Ajax. I thought it was working well, but later realized that the likes are only getting incremented for the first post. Here is the HTML page

```
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
    {% for it in lists %}
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="thumbnail">
              {% if lt.image%}
              <!img src="{{ lt.image.url }}" class="img-responsive">
              {% endif %}
              <img src="{{ lt.image.url }}" alt="...">
              <div class="caption">
                <h3><a href="{% url 'posts:detail' lt.id %}">{{ lt.title}}</a><small>  {{ lt.timestamp|timesince }} ago</small></h3>
                <p>{{ lt.content|linebreaks|truncatechars:120 }}</p>
                <p><a href="{% url 'posts:detail' lt.id %}" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View</a></p>
                        <button id="likes" data-catid="{{ lt.id }}" class="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-thumbs-up" type="button">
                        Like {% if lt.likes > 0 %} {{lt.likes}} {% endif %}
                        </button>         
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

And this is the Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#likes').click(function(event){
        alert("button")
        event.preventDefault();
        var element=$(this);
        $.ajax({
            url : '/posts/like_category/',
            type : 'GET',
            data : { category_id: element.attr("data-catid")},
            success : function(response){
                element.html(' ' + response)
            }
        });
    });

});
```

The likes are Incremented only for the first post, I Think the problem is with my HTML page. Please help me to sort out this problem.

Comment: IDs must be unique so `#id` selectors also select only one element. Use classes instead.